# GHUnit with cocoa pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, gh-unit

I am managing project dependencies using cocoa **pods**. I added `GHUnit` target into my project and it is working fine.

I have a problem in importing  pods **(cocoa pods)** files into `GHUnit` target.

For example, `AFNetwork` is added to my pod, how can I import `AFJSONRequestOperation` header into a `GHUnit` test class? (I conldn'd find the files when trying to add them manually in build phase).

Comment: Here is a tutorial showing how to properly use AFNetworking, GHUnit, and CocoaPods http://nscookbook.com/2013/03/recipe-18-unit-testing-with-ghunit-cocoapods/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15398732/902968). The idea is that you have to link your pods with both targets of your application with `link_with` which is documented [here](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#link_with).

Example:

```
link_with ['MainTarget', 'TestTarget']
```

This will link all your pods with both so you can use the other pods in your tests.